# Parse saveEventually not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, save, cloud

I just updated my Parse SDK from 1.6.0 to 1.6.5 and now I get an error saying that `saveEventually` is missing a parameter. The documentation doesn't say anything changed so I'm confused on what is going on....

Comment: Post your actual code to show how you are trying to call it.

Comment: I just figured it out...

Answer (score -2):

Turns out you have to add the Bolts framework to the bridge heading.

That's new.